# Bad substitution error in appending a variable to a filename (renaming file)

Tags: bash

I tried to append a variable value to a filename and get the file name as:

```
Page_variablevalue
```

It gives bad substitution error when at line:

```
mv "$page.txt" "page_${variablevalue}.txt"
```

Please help.

Comment: Your command, as given, looks just fine.  However, tell us what values are of the the `page` and `variablename` variables?

Answer (score 1):

Try this command,

```
mv /path/file.txt /path/"$var"
```

`var` is the variable name which stores a string value.

Comment: +1 for only quoting the part of the string that needed to be quoted, namely the variable, which could contain spaces.